# (Firebase|Ionic) GoogleAuth delayed response wrong return before finished?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

on my login Page i've got a button that is calling this function

```js
  googleauth(){
    if(this.auth.signInGoogle()){
        alert("1");
        if(this.auth.getcurrentUser().displayName){
          alert("2");
          this.gameStatus.players[0].name = this.auth.getcurrentUser().displayName;
          alert("3");
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
        }
    }else{
      alert("googleauth else");
    }
  }
```

in my auth provider this is the signInGoogle() function

```js
signInGoogle(){
   this.googleplus.login({
      'webClientId' : '',
      'offline' : true
    })
   .then((res)=>{
    const firecreds = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken);
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firecreds).then((success)=>{
          alert("auth1");
          return true;
        }).catch((err)=>{
          alert('Firebase auth failed ' + err);
      })    
   }).catch((err)=>{
    alert('Error:' + err);
      return false;
   });   
  }
```

This is whats displayed via alert on my phone when i click on the button:
googleauth else
auth1

**auth1** is above `return true`, so the stuff inside `if(this.auth.signInGoogle()){..}` should be called, but instead the `else {..}` part is called.
the **googleauth else** alert is called before the **auth1** alert is there something like a waiting function i have to use? is the functions running in threads? how can this happen? how could i fix it?

**Thank you guys in advance**

---

**Edit**

my account is shown in firebase authentication page
The whole **authProvider**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { GamestatusProvider } from '../../providers/gamestatus/gamestatus';
@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {
  constructor(public googleplus: GooglePlus) {}
  signInGoogle(){
   this.googleplus.login({
      'webClientId' : '..',
      'offline' : true
    })
   .then((res)=>{
    const firecreds = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken);
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firecreds).then((success)=>{
          alert("auth1");
          return true;
        }).catch((err)=>{
          alert('Firebase auth failed ' + err);
      })    
   }).catch((err)=>{
    alert('Error:' + err);
      return false;
   });   
  }
  getcurrentUser(){
   return firebase.auth().currentUser;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
export class LoginPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public auth: AuthProvider, public gameStatus: GamestatusProvider) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
      if(firebaseUser){ 
               this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);        
      } 
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }
  anonAuth(){
    this.auth.signInAnonym();    
  }
  googleAuth(){
    this.auth.signInGoogle();  
  }
}
```

```js
export class AuthProvider {
  constructor(public googleplus: GooglePlus, public gameStatus: GamestatusProvider) {}
  signInAnonym(){
    firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();        
  }
  signInGoogle(){
   this.googleplus.login({
      'webClientId' : webClientIdGooglePlusApi,
      'offline' : true
    })
   .then((res)=>{
    const firecreds = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken);
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firecreds).then((success)=>{          
          return true;
        }).catch((err)=>{
          alert('Firebase auth failed ' + err);
      })    
   }).catch((err)=>{
    alert('Error:' + err);
      return false;
   });   
  }

  signOut(){
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }
 }
```

is Working, but i still would love to know why my first attempt didnt worked?